# Stay on Same Page or Redirect Old Page after Delete Action

Tags: php, mysqli

I have PHP page called index.php where I am displaying some data in table. I have action button called Delete from where user can delete record from table like below

```
<td><center><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $apl_installations_row['installation_id'];?>">
                                        <i class="fas fa-times"style="color:red"></i>
                                    </a></center></td>
```

My delete.php is like below

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once "../sessioncheck.php";
include_once "config.php";
$user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];

$update = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM apl_installations WHERE installation_id = ? AND client_id = ?");
$update->bind_param('ii', $id, $user_id);
$update->execute();
$update->close();
?>
```

Its opening new page called delete.php and stay on same page after record get delete. I want keep user on same page called index.php or want back on index.php after delete record. 
Let me know if someone can help me for do it. Sorry I am learning PHP and have not good knowledge of it.
Thanks

Comment: go add echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="3; '.$url.'">'; with $url being $url='index.php'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php 
    session_start();
    include_once "../sessioncheck.php";
    include_once "config.php";
    $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

    $update = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM apl_installations WHERE installation_id = ? AND client_id = ?");
    $update->bind_param('ii', $id, $user_id);
    $update->execute();
    $update->close();
    header("Location: http://example.com/index.php");
    die();


    ?>
```

You just redirect again index.php page

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect user to index.php at the end of delete.php by either using

`header("Location: http://localhost:8080/test/index.php");`

OR using JS as below

```
<script>window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/test/index.php";</script>
```

Note: Replace http://localhost:8080/test/index.php with your URL.

Also a better option would be to use jQuery AJAX